# Saving state for a list of items in Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm having some trouble with state for a list of items. I want to save state for each item, as well as some state for the entire list. Any thoughts or guidance for my implementation? Errors marked with "###". Thanks. Also, how do I format a pasted-in set of code lines? ctrl-K just blew them away, and adding pre/code tags still gets a red complaint. I just added 4 spaces to each line to get it to work.

```
class TruffleListScreenList extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  TruffleListScreenListState createState() {
    return TruffleListScreenListState();
  }
}

class TruffleListScreenListState extends State<TruffleListScreenList> {
  List<TruffleItemState> truffleItems = [
    TruffleItemState("chocolate", "images/IMG_1252.JPG"),
    TruffleItemState("mint", "images/IMG_1253.JPG"),
    TruffleItemState("tooti-frutti", "images/IMG_1254.JPG"),
    TruffleItemState("peanut butter", "images/IMG_1255.JPG"),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView(
      children: truffleItems,   ### The argument type 'List TruffleItemState' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List Widget'
    );
  }
}

class TruffleItem extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  TruffleItemState createState() {
    return TruffleItemState();   ### 2 required argument(s) expected, but 0 found.
  }
}

class TruffleItemState extends State<TruffleItem> {
  String name;
  String imageFile;
  int qty;
  bool add;

  TruffleItemState(this.name, this.imageFile);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {  // build a row of stuff as a list item
    return Row(

    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The structure for the Widgets looks good: one for the list, one for each list item.

The next step is to make a list of Widgets for each `TruffleItem` and use that in the children for the ListView. To achieve that, you'll want to use the map function on the List class. Also, you have to pass the parameters twice, as of my experience. Once for the StatefulWidget, then replicate to the State.

Your code should look like this:

```
class TruffleListScreenList extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  TruffleListScreenListState createState() {
    return TruffleListScreenListState();
  }
}

class TruffleListScreenListState extends State<TruffleListScreenList> {
  List<TruffleItemState> truffleItems = [
    TruffleItemState("chocolate", "images/IMG_1252.JPG"),
    TruffleItemState("mint", "images/IMG_1253.JPG"),
    TruffleItemState("tooti-frutti", "images/IMG_1254.JPG"),
    TruffleItemState("peanut butter", "images/IMG_1255.JPG"),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView(
        // Map each item to a widget, then turn into a list.
        children: truffleItems.map((item) => TruffleItem(item.name, item.imageFile)).toList(),
    );
  }
}

class TruffleItem extends StatefulWidget {
  final String name;
  final String imageFile;

  TruffleItem(this.name, this.imageFile);

  @override
  TruffleItemState createState() {
    return TruffleItemState();
  }
}

class TruffleItemState extends State<TruffleItem> {
  int qty;
  bool add;

  TruffleItemState();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {  // build a row of stuff as a list item
    return Row(
        // Use the variables like widget.name or widget.imageFile
    );
  }
}
```

As said in the comments by Richard Heap:

> "Don't pass the name and imageFile down to TruffleItemState. Instead,
>   you can access them from there as widget.name and widget.imageFile
>   respectively."

Comment: Don't pass the name and imageFile down to TruffleItemState. Instead, you can access them from there as `widget.name` and `widget.imageFile` respectively.

Comment: Thanks @George, that works great. But some of the item and itemState class usage is still not clear to me. I'll have to read up some more on state handling. Your "suggest you pass the whole Item", does that refer to the "truffleItems" declaration, meaning I should be using "TruffleItem" instead? So change list type and object type to that?

Comment: Thanks @RichardHeap. Are you suggesting calling TruffleItemState with no arguments in TruffleItem's createState call? Does that mean I should ditch TruffleItemState's 2 argument constructor? As previously mentioned, I guess I have some state documentation to review.

Comment: Yes, remove name and imageFile from TruffleItemState and remove the constructor. Then replace any references in State to name with widget.name.

Comment: @gkd720 Glad to help! Also, I have just noticed that you actually have a List of TruffleItemStates already, and not a list of Truffles. Are you sure that worked correctly?

Comment: @George: No. I now see that the truffleItems list should probably be up/out a level, since it will reinitialize the list (in TruffleListScreenListState) whenever I navigate into this screen, which is not what I want. I'm trying to digest [https://flutter.io/docs/development/ui/interactive] on state existence and handling. My current goal is to just be able to see the dropdown-picked value in a row (implementation not shown above) and this works. Thanks for looking into this.